# What is meant by variable = (matrix,scalar) in Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

```
a=magic(5)
k=a,3
```

When I print `k`, it simply shows `a`.

```
m=size(a,3)
n=size(a,6)
```

when I print `m` and `n`, they print different values.

Anyone please explain what this function is?

Comment: it gives syntax  error!

Comment: @OmG It doesn't.  This is valid MATLAB syntax, though completely useless... except when you're code golfing! il_raffa's answer holds in MATLAB as well.

Comment: @rayryeng the title of the question is in Octave. and this code has syntax error in Octave.

Comment: @OmG No it doesn't.  Tested in Octave 4.0.3.  https://gist.github.com/rayryeng/7738ff3406ef56948a0e35b8640d3142

Comment: Where did you get this code? What are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Octave 4.2.1

```
k=a,3
```

assigns the matrix `a` to the variable `k`, then, as a second instruction, prints on the CommandWindow the value `3`.

The `,` (comma) is used in order to have two instruction on the same row.

An alterntive could be replacing the `,` with the `;` which has the effect of suppressing the output on the CommandWindow of the assignment `k=a`

With respect to

```
m=size(a,3)
n=size(a,6)
```

the second parameter n the call to `size` specifies the `dimension` of the matrix (the first parameter) for which you want to know the size.

`a` is a two "dimensional" matrix of size `(5 x 5)` while the instruction `size(a,3)` looks for the size of the third dimension of `a`.

In a similar way, `size(a,6)` looks for the size of the `a`'s sixth dimension. In these case, the `a` is considered as `(5 x 5 x 1)` and `(5 x 5 x 1 x 1 x 1 x 1)`

The return value, for is `1`

This is the output in the CommandWondow:

```
>> a=magic(5)

a =

   17   24    1    8   15
   23    5    7   14   16
    4    6   13   20   22
   10   12   19   21    3
   11   18   25    2    9

>> k=a,3

k =

   17   24    1    8   15
   23    5    7   14   16
    4    6   13   20   22
   10   12   19   21    3
   11   18   25    2    9

ans =  3

>> m=size(a,3)

m =  1
>> n=size(a,6)

n =  1
```

Answer (score 2):

In matlab / octave, there are three ways to terminate an expression (e.g. `1+2`):

- With a semicolon `;`
- With a comma `,`
- With a newline (i.e. pressing enter)

The first one (i.e. the semicolon) when used, evaluates the expression, but *suppresses its output*. The other two (i.e. the comma and the newline), both evaluate the statement *and* also *display its result*.

Why have both a comma and a newline? Because, with a comma, you can evaluate multiple expressions on the same line (and have all of them display their results).

<sub>Note: Given the fact that most people write their expressions in separate lines, the comma tends not to be used very much, so it is less known.</sub>

Examples:

```
octave:1> 1+2, 3+4
ans =  3
ans =  7

octave:2> 1+2; 3+4;

octave:3> 1+2; 3+4
ans =  7

octave:4> 1+2, 3+4;
ans =  3

octave:5> for i = 1:3; i; end % output in each iteration is suppressed

octave:6> for i = 1:3; i, end % whereas with a comma, output is not suppressed
i =  1
i =  2
i =  3
```

---

Therefore your statements:

```
a = magic(5)
k = a, 3
```

are essentially equivalent to

```
a = magic(5)      % newline used: display value of a after assignment
k = a,            % comma used, assign value of a to k, then display k
3                 % newline used: displays the value '3' after pressing enter
```

---

Furthermore the `size` function doesn't do what you think it does. `size(a,3)` returns the size of array `a` in the `3`rd dimension.